# How to run dot(.) commands on sqlite iOS objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Need a solution to run dot(.) commands in iOS sqlite3.
I am stuck at where I wanted to run some dot(.) terminal commands for SQLite.
Wanted to run the following SQLite terminal commands on iOS device programmatically;

```
sqlite3 $databaseName
.mode insert
.output $databaseName.sql
.dump
```

Tried several solutions to run this command, but didn't found a solution yet.

Welcome to any suggestions or answers related to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What business does your iOS app have with Terminal commands?  The Process class is not even available for iOS.

Comment: @ElTomato I am dealing with the corruption of DB, so trying to solve that using this command.
As I have solved the corruption in DB by running specific commands along with the one described above.
Is there any other way to solve corruption in SQLite Database other than this?

Comment: It sounds like you are a district attorney, but I don't know what 'corruption of DB' means.  If you are going to deal with an SQLite database file, you must learn how to run SQL commands AFTER accessing the database.

Comment: @ElTomato Data corruption is like NULL value assignment in the DB even after I have always taken care of NULL value check before insertion in the database.

Comment: Dot-commands are implemented by the sqlite3 command line tool; they're not part of the library itself. You have to write code to do what they do if you want to replicate them in your program.